# Подстановка имени константы класса из строки в php

Tags: php, const

Есть класс **SiteIds**, у которого есть константа **ENCA** с каким то значением внутри. Каким образом можно получить значение этой константы подставив вместо имени строку "ENCA"? подробнее в коде.
Сейчас:

```
<?php
SiteIds::ENCA;
?>
```

Хочу, чтобы работало так:

```
<?php
SiteIds::$config['siteId'];
?>
```

Если инфы мало, предоставлю более развернутый код.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нужно воспользоваться функцией `constant`, которая как раз делает, что тебе надо. Вот пример из мануала:

```
<?php

class foo {
    const test = 'foobar!';
}

$const = 'test';

var_dump(constant('foo::'. $const)); // string(7) "foobar!"
```

Comment: Покрутил я код, но не получилось, всеравно спасибо за помощь)